# how to set a bigger font size using jquery for the whole page?

Tags: jquery

how to set a bigger font size using jquery for the whole page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fool-proof and for all scenarios, but as close as you could get (without getting much more complicated) would be setting the `font-size` or `zoom`, like this:

```
$("body").css("font-size", "2em");
//or:
$("body").css("zoom", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically do something like

```
var $scale = $("<div>").attr("id", "scale").css("font-size", "120%");
$("body").wrapInner($scale);
```

as this give a little more control than directly altering `body` and allows you to revert back to the original size a bit easier.  You can also extend this with classes and CSS definitions for switching between different sizes pretty easily.